# How To Test A Backout Queue?

Tags: spring, websphere, ibm-mq

I have created a Backout Queue for a Queue in the MQ. I am using WebSphere and Spring JMS to send Messages to the MQ.
Now I want to Test If the newly created Backout QUeue is handling the Poison Messages. How can I Test if it is working properly?

Comment: To state the obvious, send a poison message.  For example something you know your application will not handle.  Alternately modify your application to backout messages instead of committing them.

Comment: Also you need to set backout threshold (BOTHRESH) on the queue so that JMS can move the message to backout queue after BOTHRESH is reached.

Comment: The MQ already has BO Queue Setup for the Main Queue with the BO Threshold set. I'm just not able to test it. I also tried using PUT Messages to send invalid messages but still not able to test it. The Primary Queue uses XML as Input Messages.